# Return true from enumerable that calls function unless that function ever returns false

Tags: c#, comparative-review, linq, error-handling

Is there a tighter way to write this code?

```
foreach(var processName in processNames)
{
    bool launched = launch(processName);
    if (!launched)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

I'm not sure what this kind of approach is called. But basically if any false the whole thing is false, otherwise it's true. The closest I can get is:

```
return !processNames.Any(process => !launch(process));
```

but I think the first approach is better because it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually positive conditions are much easier to understand than negative ones and even easier then two negatives in the same expression. You can flip it and get rid of both negations by using `All` instead:

```
return processNames.All(process => launch(process));
```

Now that the nagations are gone you can further shorten this by removing the lambda:

```
return processNames.All(launch);
```

This is possible because the `launch` method signature matches the delegate  `Func<string, bool>` required by `All`.

Comment: geez, that is the perfect answer. I don't think I knew there was a .All. Thanks.